# Using Pillow to find DPI

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, dpi

I'm trying to find out the DPI of an image using the Pillow module.

I'm doing this

```
image = Image.open("image.jpeg")
print(image.info["dpi"])
```

which returns

```
(300, 300)
```

Why is this a tuple? I was expecting a single value. What do the two values relate to and which should I use to give me the same value I see in photoshop?

Comment: The tuple means 300 pixels width 300 pixels height

Answer (score 4):

The docs do not say much about this, but I've gone roughly through source code and it seems that this refers to DPI in x and y axis ([look at search results](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/search?q=dpi&unscoped_q=dpi))

Especially [this](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/fdbd719da4c77c7e23e2e9e9b71d0d177f2d3369/src/libImaging/Jpeg.h#L85) suggests that there could exist something as non-square pixels.

Comment: This seems like the right answer. Non-square pixels are – well, not _common_, but definitely a thing in video, and what is video if not just a bunch of images one after the other. :)